# Combine two rows into one based on identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, pivot

My dataset looks like this:

| LBID | ADDRESS | FI | LI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 7283 | JOHN | SMITH |
| 101 | 7283 | JANE | JONES |

Since John and Jane have the same LBID and the same Address, I want the output to look like this:

| LBID | ADDRESS | FI | LI | FI2 | LI2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 7283 | JOHN | SMITH | JANE | JONES |

I checked on Stack Overflow for similar issues but they all deal with columns that have NULLs.  None of mine have NULLs.

I tried `STUFF`, `STRING_AGG` and `JOIN` operations, but none can get it how I want it. My latest attempt was:

```
SELECT LBID, ADDRESS, STRING_AGG(FI, '& ') AS FI, LI
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY LBID, ADDRESS, LI
```

but since the last names are not the same it still puts it on two different rows.

Any thought on how this can be done?

Comment: Are you assuming the fixed schema "LBID, ADDRESS, FI, LI, FI2, LI2", or do you expect to have even more than 2 duplicate records to be reconduced to single record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume a fixed schema with two record duplicates at best, you can count your duplicate records with a `ROW_NUMBER` window function. Since it can assume value 2 at best (two duplicates), you can solve the problem with a typical pivot approach and extract the corresponding rownum for each row.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LBID, ADDRESS ORDER BY FI) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT LBID, ADDRESS,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN FI END) AS FI1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN LI END) AS LI1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN FI END) AS FI2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN LI END) AS LI2
FROM cte
GROUP BY LBID, ADDRESS
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/qFRyMA7w).

Output:

| LBID | ADDRESS | FI | LI | FI2 | LI2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 7283 | JOHN | SMITH | JANE | JONES |

---

If you have more than 2 duplicate records, it's sufficient to add more pivotal elements to your final query, and extracting coupled "rn=", as per following pseudocode:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LBID, ADDRESS ORDER BY FI) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT LBID, ADDRESS,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN FI END) AS FI1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN LI END) AS LI1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN FI END) AS FI2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN LI END) AS LI2,
       ...
       ...
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = <n> THEN FI END) AS FI<n>
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = <n> THEN LI END) AS LI<n>
FROM cte
GROUP BY LBID, ADDRESS
```

---

If you don't know how many duplicate records per (LBID, ADDRESS) you can have at most, you can run a query to know that value:

```
SELECT TOP(1) COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM tab
GROUP BY LBID, ADDRESS
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

This value will be the amount of couple of pivotal elements to extract:

```
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = <n> THEN FI END) AS FI<n>
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = <n> THEN LI END) AS LI<n>
```

for the specific case of your sample table, 2 (as per first query).

---

And if have so many duplicate records per single address, and want a generalized approach, you would go towards dynamic querying. Yet that approach could be less performant and prone to SQL injection.

Comment: Perfect, yes!  This will account for instances where there may be more than 2 duplicate LBIDs.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT LBID, ADDRESS, STRING_AGG(CONCAT(CONCAT(FI, ' '), LI), ' & ') AS FI
FROM mytable
GROUP BY LBID, ADDRESS
```

output:

| LBID | ADDRESS | FI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 7283 | JOHN SMITH & JANE JONES |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/oAjrUmW2)

or:

```
SELECT m1.LBID, m1.ADDRESS, m1.FI, m1.LI, m2.FI as FI2, m2.LI as LI2
FROM mytable m1
INNER JOIN mytable m2 ON m1.LBID = m2.LBID and m1.FI > m2.FI
```

The `>` makes John come first, if you want/need to mention Jane first please change that to a `<`

output:

| LBID | ADDRESS | FI | LI | FI2 | LI2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 7283 | JOHN | SMITH | JANE | JONES |

Comment: Thank you so much!  This works when there are at most 2 duplicate LBIDs.  I am unable to upvote because of reputation but thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, it is not a final answer and a dirty hack, but may be useful

```
WITH CTE(LBID,    ADDRESS,    FI ,          LI)AS
(
  SELECT 101,     7283,       'JOHN' ,        'SMITH'    UNION ALL
  SELECT 101,     7283 ,      'JANE',         'JONES'
),
CTE2 AS
(  
  SELECT C.LBID,C.ADDRESS,C.FI,C.LI,
  ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY C.LBID,C.ADDRESS ORDER BY(SELECT NULL ))AS XCOL
 FROM CTE AS C
)
SELECT C.LBID,C.ADDRESS,C.FI,C.LI, X.FI,X.LI
FROM CTE2 AS C
JOIN CTE2 AS X ON C.XCOL=X.XCOL+1
```